# Techniques to reduce elbow pain during back day

Tags: pull-ups

Heads up: I have a muscle imbalance between my left and right back, my right back is more developed.

Yesterday I went to the gym for my usual back day. I started with perhaps 3 sets of neutral close grip pullups, at 7-5-4 respectively. Then, I did perhaps 3 sets of bent over dumbell rows at 8 reps. Usually I do these with 15kg dumbells, but I managed to do 20kg yesterday with good form.

Now, I then jumped on to try to do more pull-ups (same grip_ and immediately felt a little pain in the region between my inner elbow and tricep. I have read that this is called the *medial epicondyle*.

> > **My question is:** What is the reason for this pain?

From watching this video [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S_93yIKub98) it could be that my forearms are taking too much of a load. He suggests to use neutral grip pullups, but this is what I am already doing! What can I do about my technique in future to reduce this problem?  Any recommended stretches?

At the moment, that region of my arm is a little sensitive to touch. I'll be seeing my physio tomorrow.

Comment: I wouldn't mess around with elbow tendinitis. The only thing you can do is completely rest and stop hurting it. In the past I've had that problem when I've done bouncy movements.

Answer (score 1):

That sounds like "Golfer's Eblow".  I can only count the number of times I've golfed on one hand, but I've been suffering on and off with this condition for years. I first discovered it after several sessions of preacher and spider curls about 10 years ago; a few years later, I had a recurrence doing pull ups on a cross beam, and again, after completing Stew Smith's 10 day pull up program.

I'm not a doc, but generally speaking, it's caused by repeatedly stressing flexors and extension in the forearms/fingers.

I went to the doctor for it originally, and he told me to take 400 mg of NSAIDs/day, and lay off the workouts causing the problem until the pain stopped.  This worked, but nipping pulls up from any routine for weeks/months really sucks; it's especially frustrating when the rest of your body is fully capable.

Taking my doc's advice into consideration, I slowly worked them back into my routine by doing light lat pull-down work, focusing intensely on the eccentric lat squeeze (resistance band assisted pull-ups are also "effective").

That said, I recently discovered "elbow smashing" and voodoo floss (bike tubing also works), and it's helped me tremendously.  Here are a couple videos to get you started:

[Banish Your Elbow Bench, Dip, Pull Up Pain, You Don’t Really Play Golf or Tennis Do You?](http://www.mobilitywod.com/2012/04/banish-your-elbow-bench-dip-pull-up-pain-you-dont-really-play-golf-or-tennis-do-you/)

[Epicondylitis-ness? Voodoo it](http://www.mobilitywod.com/2012/02/burpee-smoked-elbows-epicondylitis-ness-voodoo-it/)

I feel for ya, pal...sucks and super frustrating, but experiment with the methods above, and I think you'll see a turnaround.